# Between 1960-1964 I saw a trailer with a man in a suit surrounded by very tall desks with judges with red skin. It was dark, modern, and alienating

Tags: story-identification, movie

Between 1960 and 1964 I saw a trailer. A man is standing in a big, dark space. He is wearing a business suit. Surrounding him are a group of judges. The judges are seated, and are positioned higher than the man on trial. Each judge has red skin, so the judges are devil-like supernatural characters. It is possible that the high desks that the judges are sitting behind are part of a somewhat intimidating c-shaped elongated desk.

It is quite clear that the man is on trial, and he almost certainly did nothing wrong, and the system he is facing is both cruel and supernatural-based.

What is so disturbing about this: the normalcy of it all. It looked dark, direct, sterile, modern, and alienating. In other words, there were no angry dogs, no cobwebs, no bothersome flies, no dripping walls.

Do you know what the title of this film is?

Comment: You are saying you saw a trailer 60 years ago, which implies this was a major film made around that time? I have been watching films since the late 1960s and this sure does not ring a bell. All flies are bothersome unless you are a spider or a lizard (or a fly of the same species). Do you think this was an American or English film?

Comment: Terrible match as only red skin in common - But Masque of the Red Death is 1964 and death is judgemental https://youtu.be/IAmFzCwD55Q

Comment: Apart from the skin color (especially since the movie is mostly monochrome) this sounds like "The Trial" (1962). This is based on a Kafka novel and absurdist rather than supernatural, but it is not always easy to tell the difference. Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trial_(1962_film).

Comment: Was it a movie trailer, or perhaps an advertisement for something in a series such as an episode of The Outer Limits?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to suggest this is "The Deadly Dream" (1971).

It was a tele-movie that involved exactly what you're describing - Lloyd Bridges stars as a business-suited man who has recurring dreams of a "Tribunal" where devilish judges stare down at him and enact a trial. He awakens horrified each time, wondering what it all means.

From [Turner Classic Movies](https://prod-www.tcm.com/tcmdb/title/462908/the-deadly-dream#overview):

> A research scientist is driven to the brink by a recurring dream that he is marked for death by a mysterious tribunal, and soon he is unable to separate his dreams from reality -- and vice versa.

Here is a poster showing the shadows of the judges.

[image: poster]

And a still of Bridges in his suit:

[image: Bridges]

Obviously, this movie is a decade after your recall.